# How to uninstall silverlight 4 OOB application programmatically

Tags: silverlight

How to unistall Silverlight OOB application programatically??

Can we do this using Automation factory to run the uninstall query directly? If so, can anyone provide a sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sllauncher.exe to uninstall the application using the /uninstall parameter

```
Usage: SLLauncher.exe [app_id] [debug] [/install:<file path to XAP>] [/emulate:<file path to XAP>] [/overwrite] /origin:<original app uri> /uninstall /shortcut:<desktop|startmenu|desktop+startmenu|none> [/pid]
```